Keep duplicate dictionaries of a list of dictionaries
In my playbook, I have a list of dictionaries. I want to keep only duplicate dictionaries.
Basically it is something like:
{   
   "l": [
        {
            "a": "d",
            "b": "e",
            "c": "f",
        },
        {
            "a": "ggg",
            "b": "hhh",
            "c": "iii",
        },
        {
            "a": "jjj",
            "b": "kkk",
            "c": "lll",
        },
        {
            "a": "d",
            "b": "e",            
            "c": "f",
        }
        ]
}

I tried different things but at some point I realized I was perhaps reinventing the wheel. I couldn't find any module though.
EDIT
Here's what I've managed to do with jq, it's not very elegant because I'm reprocessing the list for each element (and I'm also making nulls to filter them afterwards). What reassures me is that gpt hasn't managed to do it at all (despite my insistence). The list is contained in the data object because the filter references that list explicitly.
---
- name: Filter duplicates from a list of dictionaries
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    jq_filter: '[ .l[] as $item | if ((.l | map(select(. == $item)) | length) > 1) then $item else null end | select (. != null) ] | unique'
    data:
      l:
        - { a: "ddd", b: "eee", c: "fff" }
        - { a: "ggg", b: "hhh", c: "iii" }
        - { a: "jjj", b: "kkk", c: "lll" }
        - { a: "ddd", b: "eee", c: "fff" }
        - { a: "jjj", b: "kkk", c: "lll" }
  tasks:
    - name: debug list
      debug:
        var: data
    - name: Process list
      shell: echo '{{ data | to_json }}' | jq '{{ jq_filter }}'
      register: shell_output
    - name: get duplicates
      set_fact:
        duplicates: "{{ shell_output.stdout_lines | join | from_json }}"
    - name: debug duplicates
      debug:
        var: duplicates 

I accepted the answer with a custom filter

Does Ansible: How to get duplicate items from list? answer your question?

@U880D I read that answer to, most are not applicable for object type. except the python filter. But thanks to your comment I read it one more time and noticed the use of json_query to extract counted elements. I think I can make a request with json_query filter (if it is like jq). perhaps it will solve my problem in one  step.

I think you're looking for
l | difference(l | unique) | unique

Unfortunately, the filter difference doesn't work with lists of dictionaries. But, you can write a filter on your own. For example,
shell> cat filter_plugins/duplicates.py 
def duplicates(l):
    return [i for i in l if l.count(i) > 1]


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'duplicates': duplicates,
        }

Then, the playbook below
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    l:
      - {a: d, b: e, c: f}
      - {a: ggg, b: hhh, c: iii}
      - {a: jjj, b: kkk, c: lll}
      - {a: d, b: e, c: f}

    result: "{{ l | duplicates | unique }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result | to_yaml

gives probably what you want
  result:
    - {a: d, b: e, c: f}



If you want to select the exact frequency, create the below filter
shell> cat filter_plugins/dict_counter.py 
def dict_counter(l):
    u = [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in l)]
    return [{'dict': i, 'count': l.count(i)} for i in u]


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_counter': dict_counter,
        }

gives
  l | dict_counter:
    - count: 2
      dict: {a: d, b: e, c: f}
    - count: 1
      dict: {a: ggg, b: hhh, c: iii}
    - count: 1
      dict: {a: jjj, b: kkk, c: lll}

Then, the below declaration gives the same result
  result: "{{ l | dict_counter
                | selectattr('count', 'eq', 2)
                | map(attribute='dict') }}"



Oh, even simpler solution than under Find duplicates in Python list of dictionaries ... +1
